# Frases em inglês ao sinalizar postagem

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

Existem falhas na tradução nos seguintes locais:

`Sinalizar` > `ela deve ser encerrada por outro motivo...`: neste local o título da janela está `Flagging`. Acredito qu deveria ser `Sinalizando`.

Selecionando a opção `Descontextualizado` existem mais duas opções, também em inglês. Uma é a cópia da anterior. A segunda está abaixo, junto com a sugestão:

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

.

> Esta questão pertence a outro site na rede  Stack Exchange.

Comment: @bfavaretto Você colou o link errado. Ta apontando pra essa mesma pergunta. ;)

Comment: Ops... Era esta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/655/erro-de-traducao-em-flagging-esta-pergunta-nao-e-daqui-porque

Comment: @bfavaretto É verdade. Acho então que vou remover a parte duplicada e deixar o resto .

Comment: O texto de "Flagging" já foi corrigido, já a parte referente ao texto de "This question belongs..." foi passado pros devs

Comment: Não é por nada mas eu acho que a tradução **não** deveria ser feita. Até porque se a questão pertence a outro site SE tem de estar em EN não?